# How to catch the map event that is triggered after the start of a drag, pan, or zoom?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What is the Map event that is triggered after the start of a drag, pan, or zoom?
In API V2 it was movestart (This event is fired when the map view starts changing) but V3 does not have this event so I wonder what the equivalent of the "movestart" event is in V3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the available [google.maps.Map events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map).  There is a dragstart for drag; for pan or zoom, it looks like there is only the event that fires when they change.

- drag
- dragstart
- dragend
- center_changed
- zoom_changed

Answer (score 1):

On the map you have `dragstart`.  You also have events like `zoom_changed`, `bounds_changed`, `center_changed` and `projection_changed`.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Map

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent in V3. But you may implement it by observing the `bounds_changed` -event:

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(){
          google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this, 'bounds_changed', function(){
             google.maps.event.trigger(this,'movestart');});});

        //test the event 
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'movestart',function(){
              console.log('movestart triggered')});
```